# Difference between get vs post

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes, node-modules

I'm a beginner in Node JS. I'm a bit confused with `get` vs `post`. when the browser `request` data from the server then will the browser get or post.?

Comment: If you are using express version >= 4.16 body parser is not necessary. Body parser lib comes bundled with express.

Comment: Perhaps you could focus on one question at a time?  And for any given question, indicate also what problem you're having or what you're trying to do that isn't working.  For example, in your first question, what happens when you try that?  Do you get a specific error?  What differences do you see between those two approaches and why do you think that might be important?  If you're just looking for tutorials and learning resources, your favorite search engine is really the place to start for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After installing express and requiring it. Why can't I use directly
>
> `express.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));`

Because `.use()` is a method on the `app` object, not on the express object.  Further, body-parser is built into Express now, so you should be using:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

> and why should I write
>
> `const app = express();`

Express is a library that allows you to create web servers and manage them.  To do that, you need to create an express instance with `const app = express()`.  It is analogous to Express is the `class` and you need to create an `instance` of that class in order to use it.  Technically, `express` is a factory function (a function you call to create instances you can use), not a class, but the concept is the same.

> what is urlencoded({extended: true}); ? can you please explain in simple words.

This creates middleware for your app that knows how to parse one specific type of request.  The urlencoded mime-type typically comes from form post requests from a browser.  `urlencoded` is the method that the form data from the browser form is packaged and sent to the web server.  For your server to use that form data, some code has to unpack it from this text format and turn it into Javascript that you can use.  This middleware can do that for that specific type of data.

> What is `req.body`?

First off, the `req` object is data about the incoming request that arrived at your server.  Then, the `.body` property is where middleware that parses incoming data from the request will typically place a Javascript version of the data after it has been parsed from its text or binary form and turned into something that you can use from Javascript.   After the middleware does this, then your code can access the parsed data in `req.body`.   Further, `req.body` is usually an object with its own properties so you would access one of those properties with a property name such as `req.body.first` (or whatever the property is named that you are interested in).  If the data is coming from a browser form, then the property name will typically be the `name=xxx` attribute in the HTML form.

> If possible please recommend a good resource to learn NodeJS.

Asking for off-site learning resources is considered off-topic here.